# Is Netbeans handling indexing on C code better than Eclipse's CDT?

Tags: netbeans, eclipse-cdt

I am using CDT 8 with indigo. Basically I am quite happy with it except one thing, which is the indexer is too slow and freezes my machine after I edited some files. The code base of the project is quite large, around 2G , but I tried with CScope, it actually indexes pretty fast, ~0.5 hour compared to ~3 hours on eclipse.

I am wondering if netbeans handles indexing better ? of course with an okay code assistant.

Answer (score 0):

Not having used the NetBeans C editor much I can't say what the state of the code completion is. In recent versions of NetBeans (7 onwards) they have started using [native file system listeners](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB70#Native_Filesystem_listening) to detect code changes. I don't think the work is completed yet, however what it should mean is that indexing will become faster with each successive version.